# TACACS+ ACS 5.3 Err 'ACS: Resource not found or internal server error No information'

Tags: cisco, tacacs+

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Running: Cisco TACACS+ ACS 5.3

When I log in I see this displayed on the right pane. I still have the navigation links on the the left pane and able to launch the monitoring and reporting.

ACS: Resource not found or internal server error
No information about this error was available.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Found that this message appears if you are logged into the ACS appliance and then close the browser without logging out. Upon your return to the idle session this this error message will be displayed. Current fix is to log out and log back in.